# Pagination inTypo3

Tags: php, typo3

I have written a TYPO3 extension which lists records from database on 
pages.
Now I have to add pagination at bottom of page with 10 records on each 
page like tt_news does.

Can anybody please give me a hint

Answer (score 4):

Try the extension "Universal page browser" (http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/pagebrowse). This extension provides page browsing services to other extensions.